# Does log4j support JSON format?

Tags: java, json, log4j

Is it possible to let log4j output its logging in JSON format by only altering the `log4j.properties` / `xml` configuration files?

I make use of an old application that uses `log4j 1.2`. I only see the standard layout but no JSON layout.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

just use buildin PatternLayout is ok:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern={"debug_level":"%p","debug_timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","debug_thread":"%t","debug_file":"%F", "debug_line":"%L","debug_message":"%m"}%n
```

will out put like:

```
{
    "debug_level" : "INFO",
    "debug_timestamp" : "2016-05-26 16:37:08,938",
    "debug_thread" : "main",
    "debug_file" : "TestLogOutPut.java",
    "debug_line" : "316",
    "debug_message" : "hello i am a log message"
}
```

Comment: This will break if the message contains `"`.

Comment: This can't be work when the error message contains "\n" etc

Comment: I know it is an old subject but I got the same problem. I only have access to the log4j.xml configuration code and not to the code itself.
In .xml configuration file I try many combinaison like this:

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <pattern>
          { 'jsonPayload': { 'timestamp':"%d{ISO8601}", 'level':"%p", 'category':"%c", 'message':"%m" } }%n
        </pattern>
      </layout>

or <param name="ConversionPattern" value='{ jsonPayload: { timestamp:"%d{ISO8601}", level:"%p", category:"%c", message:"%m" } }%n'/>

Comment: Essentially a poor man's JSON that will work only in the simplest of cases.

Comment: It absolutely is, but there's no viable alternative if you're dealing with a legacy app... except abandon the JSON idea, and use a delimiter that won't clash with anything already in the log output.

Comment: If you have problems with json due to special characters( like " ), you can use this %enc{%throwable}{JSON} or %enc{%m}{JSON}

Comment: to handel escape character issue ( " ,\ ) use it like this 
`{ "message":"%enc{%m}{JSON}" }`

Comment: How to make this pattern work for stacktraces?

Answer (score 58):

this is official JSON layout

https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout

1) Add maven dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.log4j/jsonevent-layout

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonevent-layout</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>  
</dependency>
```

2) Add configuration to your `log4j.properties` file

```
 log4j.rootCategory=WARN, RollingLog
 log4j.appender.RollingLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
 log4j.appender.RollingLog.Threshold=TRACE
 log4j.appender.RollingLog.File=api.log
 log4j.appender.RollingLog.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd
 log4j.appender.RollingLog.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
```

Comment: Unfortunately step 1 conflicts with "by only altering the log4j.properties.xml configuration file" in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It is possible.
[Take a look at this link](https://github.com/michaeltandy/log4j-json)
It can generate

```
{
   "timestamp":1352412458890,
   "date":"Nov 8, 2012 10:07:38 PM",
   "hostname":"michael1",
   "username":"michael",
   "level":"INFO",
   "thread":"main",
   "classname":"uk.me.mjt.log4jjson.SimpleJsonLayoutTest",
   "filename":"SimpleJsonLayoutTest.java",
   "linenumber":25,
   "methodname":"testDemonstration",
   "message":"Example of some logging"
 }
```