# How can i log json body in in json format while running my spring boot app

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I have a spring boot application. The response body of one of the controller is a json object. When i try to log the response body using log4j logger in json, it prints the json body as string. Is there any way i can log the body in json format?

What i'm getting in the console:

```
{name:'abc',age:3}
```

what I actually want in the console:

```
{
  name:'abc',
  age:3
}
```

Comment: what's the difference between these two?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does log4j support JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387007/does-log4j-support-json-format)

Comment: @clevertension the indentation