# Json logs using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi am trying to convert my plaintext logs to json format. I used log4j for logging framework in the application.
I tried this cofiguration in log4j.properities

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern={"debug_level":"%p","debug_timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","debug_thread":"%t","debug_file":"%F", "debug_line":"%L","debug_message":"%m"}%n
```

But it didn't worked.

Can anyone help how can I use json template in log4j

[image]

Comment: How specifically didn't it work?  Is the problem that it is not doing proper JSON quoting?

Comment: yes logs were still plain tetx lines not json format

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Cloud Platform then there is a direct way to get the logs in JSON format:

1. Go to Navigation menu in console and select Cloud Logging.
2. In Cloud Logging, We have  Query results getting displayed. In Query
   results, there is a button called Actions with a down arrow.
3. Click the down arrow then we get some options, Select Download logs.
4. We get a popup there, In the format select JSON and click Download.
5. If you want more logs to be converted to JSON format check [Exporting
   logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview).
6. To get logs in a particular time frame, Click on the last 7 days
   icon on the top right side in the console and select the custom time
   range.

**NOTE**:If you are not using GCP

Please have a look at this [similar issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387007/does-log4j-support-json-format)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Nikitha. Yes, I am using GCP logging and I have tried the method you suggested. But the problem is that my application send all the logs to System.Out file( even the error logs), which are then considered as INFO severity by default even if they are error logs. Like in below sample
` {
    "textPayload": "[10/5/21 11:12:41:663 CEST] application error message",
    "insertId": "",
    "resource": {
      "type": "k8s_container"
    "severity": "INFO",
    "logName": "",
  } `
Even if my log has error message in System.out file it is treated as INFO level

Comment: If the message has an “error” word mentioned in it that is not considered as the  error logs some info logs messages  also have an error word in them , if it is the log of error then the “severity” will be “ERROR”. I.e  **"severity": "ERROR"**
Try using this query **severity=((WARNING OR NOTICE OR INFO OR DEBUG OR DEFAULT) AND (NOT ERROR))** to filter the error logs from the logs and check are you still getting error logs, I tried in my environment and I cloud exclude "severity": "ERROR" logs.

Comment: Actually that's the issue. Since all applications logs (info + error) are logged in System.out . And gcp logging considers logs in System out as "severity": "INFO"
So even when I have error logs they are getting treated as info logs.

Comment: I found one [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs) which talks about fetching the application logs in system.out . Here try to select **Any log level** to **INFO** and filter error logs from system.out. Download logs by clicking the download icon on the top right side of the list of logs and select JSON to get them downloaded in JSON format.

Comment: @Nikitha I have added a image for reference, the logs in log explorer show text payload instead of text payload I want the log to be jsonpayload. So that correct severity is filtered.

Comment: By default, logs written to the standard output are on the INFO level and logs written to the standard error are on the ERROR level. [Structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) can include a severity field, which defines the log's severity.You can write structured logs to Logging in several ways . Structuring logs using a [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging#special-payload-fields) helps you to convert your payloads to JSON format.