# How to configure JSON Logging in an Third Party App using Log4j?

Tags: java, json, kubernetes, log4j

We are using [zeebe](https://github.com/camunda/zeebe) distributed workflow engine that uses log4j as its logging framework. Its a spring boot application deployed through helm on kubernetes. Unfortunately it does not include `log4j-layout-template-json` jar that enables json logging. Any approach that requires third party app code modifications doesn't look right since the project is under active development. We would need to constantly upgrade the third party app and hence forking it would make deployments tougher.

What are some possible ways to configure it for json logging so that the logs can be shipped to EFK stack?

Thanks

Comment: I would push to generate JSON logs from the app in the 1st place but if that's not an option you can always use a custom parser/transformer when sending logs from Kubernetes pods to Elastic. What are you using to send logs to Elastic? FluentBit?

Comment: How do you deploy Zeebe? Can't you create your own container image based on the official Zeebee one such that you can download & unpack the Log4j distribution from `downloads.apache.org` in the `Dockerfile`? Maybe stating the obvious, but... Have you tried creating a Zeebee ticket with this request?

Comment: @GaëlJ - we use fluentd to push the logs to ES. Need to search what custom parsers exists that can transform textual logs to json.

Comment: @VolkanYazıcı - modifying the docker file and maintaining it for every release is a long route. Like I said we don't want to go that route unless there are no options left. Yes we created a ticket in zeebe but they have deprioritised this item. It won't be taken up soon.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is simple: you need to add `log4j-layout-template-json` to the classpath of the application and create a Docker image with the additional libraries.

The devil is in the details: every distribution has a different method to add libraries to the classpath.

Camunda Zeebe seems to be using [Appassembler](https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to create its binary distribution, which uses [this script](https://github.com/mojohaus/appassembler/blob/master/appassembler-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/org/codehaus/mojo/appassembler/daemon/script/unixBinTemplate) to boot up the application. So you have two choices:

- either you add libraries directly to `/usr/local/zeebe/lib` and your Log4j Core configuration file to `/usr/local/zeebe/config`,
- or you add libraries in another location and set the `CLASSPATH_PREFIX` environment variable accordingly.

For example you can add additional Log4j Core modules and a custom configuration file to the `/usr/local/log4j2` directory, with a Docker file like this:

```sh
FROM camunda/zeebe:latest

# Download additional Logj4 2.x artifacts
RUN apt -y update && apt -y install curl
RUN curl -SL https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/logging/log4j/2.20.0/apache-log4j-2.20.0-bin.tar.gz | \
  tar -xz --strip-components=1 --one-top-level=/usr/local/log4j2 \
    apache-log4j-2.20.0-bin/log4j-appserver-2.20.0.jar \
    apache-log4j-2.20.0-bin/log4j-jul-2.20.0.jar \
    apache-log4j-2.20.0-bin/log4j-layout-template-json-2.20.0.jar
# Add a custom configuration file
COPY log4j2.xml /usr/local/log4j2/

# Check artifacts
ARG LOG4J_APPSERVER_SUM=53d8e78277324145cde435b515b1c7f1ba02b93e7a1974411ce7c5511a8c6b69
ARG LOG4J_JUL_SUM=c9b33dffb40bd00d4889ea4700f79d87a2e4d9f92911a3a008ae18c0bb3fb167
ARG LOG4J_LAYOUT_TEMPLATE_JSON_SUM=62d2c2b8e80a74ca65d80cf2f9aa0eab3a1350349c7b03b428c5b53004cc751b
RUN sha256sum -c <<EOF
${LOG4J_APPSERVER_SUM} /usr/local/log4j2/log4j-appserver-2.20.0.jar
${LOG4J_JUL_SUM} /usr/local/log4j2/log4j-jul-2.20.0.jar
${LOG4J_LAYOUT_TEMPLATE_JSON_SUM} /usr/local/log4j2/log4j-layout-template-json-2.20.0.jar
EOF

# Add additional classpath entries
ENV CLASSPATH_PREFIX=/usr/local/log4j2/*:/usr/local/log4j2
# Use Log4j also for java.util.logging
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager

# Start the application
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: I came across [this poor man's logging config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37455869) that outputs the logger in json format. It has couple of issues like multiple line handling and escaping of embedded jsons. With the approach we will have to maintain the DockerFile and since the upgrades are very frequent, managing deployments would be a bit of a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own image for now, then create and issue and a pull request to get the missing dependency into Zeebe, so it will be there in the future.
https://github.com/camunda/zeebe/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md